# Let $X$~$U(0,5)$ & $Y$ be exponential random variable with with mean $2x$. Find the mean and variance of Y.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

Let $X$~$U(0,5)$ & $Y$ be exponential random variable with with mean $2x$.

Find the mean and variance of Y.

**My Working:**

I know that the pdf of random variable $X$ is given by: $f_X(x)=1/5$

Since $Y$ exponential random variable with mean $2x$ this means that:
$Y$~$\text{Exp}(1/2x)$ and its pdf is given by: $g_Y(y)=(1/2x)e^{-y(1/2x)}$ for all $y>=0$ and $0$ otherwise.

I don't know how to proceed further. Can anyone help please? It will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability density function for $X$ is $$f_{\small X}(x)=(1/5)\,\mathbf 1_{x\in(0..5)}$$

The *conditional* probability density function for $Y$ given $X\,{=}\,x$ is $$f_{\small Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=(1/2x)\,\mathrm e^{-y/2x}\,\mathbf 1_{y\in(0..\infty),x\in(0..5)}$$

Now, we *could* use the definitions$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) &= \iint_{(0..5){\times}(0..\infty)}(y/10x)\mathrm e^{-y/2x}\,\mathrm d \langle x,y\rangle\\[2ex]\mathsf {Var}(Y)&=\iint_{(0..5){\times}(0..\infty)}(y^2/10x)\mathrm e^{-y/2x}\,\mathrm d\langle x,y\rangle-\mathsf E(Y)^2\end{align}$$

*Buuut...*

More practically we know these expectation and variance of these distributions, so: $$\begin{split}\mathsf E(X)&=5/2\\\mathsf{Var}(X)&=25/12\\\mathsf E(Y\mid X)&=2X\\\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X)&=4X^2\end{split}$$

Why is this practical?  Well, you can now use the following:

The Law of Total Expectation says: $\mathsf E(Y) = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))$

The Law of Total Variance says: $\quad~\mathsf E(Y) = \mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))$

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have obtained the pdf of $Y|X=x$ instead of $X$. To find the pdf of $Y$, you must first find the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ by multiplying those of $Y|X=x$ and $X$ to obtain
$$
f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{10x}e^{-\frac{y}{2x}}&,\quad 0<x<5\text{ and }y>0\\
0&,\quad\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}.
$$
Now you can calculate any statistics of $X$ and $Y$ you wish.

Comment: Just to be sure if I am going correctly. I have to  calculate marginal pdf of $Y$ and then from it the mean and variance, right?

Comment: That is correct...

Comment: Just one more question, I will be needing the upper and lower limit to calculate integral involved in Marginal PDF of $Y$ and they will be values of $y$ but you haven't mentioned range of $y$ in joint $PDF$ but have mentioned only $x$. How do I tackle this?

Comment: You are correct again and I should have mentioned that $y$ could vary within $[0,\infty)$ regardless of the value of $x$. This is not a big deal in calculations, though I will add this point up in my answer. By the way, the resulting integrals do not seem to have closed forms, so you probably have to approximately solve them...

Answer (score 1):

$E(Y|X)=2X$ so $EY=E(2X)=\frac 1 5 \int_0^{5}2x dx=5$. Similarly, $E(Y^{2}|X)=2(2X)^{2}$ so $EY^{2}=E(8X^{2})=\frac 1 5 \int_0^{5}8x^{2} dx=\frac {200} 3$. Finally. the variance of $Y$ is  $\frac {200} 3-25=\frac {125} 3$

Comment: **Error:**  We were told that the conditional distribution's *mean* is $2X$, so the *parameter* is $1/2X$.